# Files becoming owned by systemd-network:systemd-journal in WSL2 and Docker setup

Tags: ubuntu, docker, systemd, file-permissions

So I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 under WSL2 with Docker. Occasionally the files mounted by Docker (could be other files as well) are getting their ownership changed from my user to `systemd-network:systemd-journal` (or in uid format `100:101`).

It's a relatively straightforward fix of `sudo chown <user>:<user> . -R`, but I'd rather figure out what causes this issue and stop it.

I'm currently unsure if it's caused by the Docker Container, Docker itself, Ubuntu 20.04 or something funky with WSL2.

I've never had this issue before with these Docker Containers in different environments...

Answer (score 0):

First you should be looking at the numeric id instead of the name. It is likely that either the image is running processes as a UID that shares the UID with the systemd uid on the host.

Anyway look at your docker image, some images allow you to control which UID or user the processes as. Perhaps you need build a new image that updates the UID.

Comment: systemd-network:100, systemd-journal:102. The user in the Docker container is running as 1000 for user and group